# El gráfico de bokeh no se muestra en Jupyter. Solo dice “Loading BokehJS …”

Tags: python-3.x, nodejs, npm, jupyter, bokeh

Inicio una sesión con `jupyter notebook`, y abro dos libros. El script que muestro a continuación (como ejemplo), en uno de los notebooks me muestra la imagen correctamente. En el otro me muestra el mensaje `“Loading BokehJS …”`

```
import numpy as np
# bokeh basics
from bokeh.plotting import figure
from bokeh.io import show, output_notebook

x = [1,2,3,4,5]
y = [2,4,6,8,10]
#output_file('line.html')
fig = figure(title = 'Line Plot example', x_axis_label = 'x', y_axis_label = 'y')
fig.line(x,y)

# Set to output the plot in the notebook
output_notebook()
show(fig)
```

¿Cuál puede ser la causa de este problema?. ¿Puede estar relacionado con el hecho de que lo primero que ejecuté fue este programa pero utilizando la función `output_file ()` para almacenar la salida en un archivo HTML?. ¿Cómo puedo evitar este problema?.

Información sacada con `!bokeh info`

```
Python version      :  3.8.3 (default, Jul  2 2020, 16:21:59) 
IPython version     :  7.16.1
Tornado version     :  6.0.4
Bokeh version       :  2.1.1
BokehJS static path :  /home/enri/anaconda3/envs/plotly/lib/python3.8/site-packages/bokeh/server/static
node.js version     :  (not installed)
npm version         :  (not installed)
```

Gracias por su ayuda.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### **Sobre Python**

Tiene que ver con las bibliotecas, el método `show` pertenece a `bokeh.plotting` y faltaría agregar el método `output_file`.

Asimismo hay que generar un archivo `html` de salida para que notebook lo pueda consumir... en tal sentido, el código base quedaría así:

```
import numpy as np

# bokeh basics
from bokeh.plotting import figure, show
from bokeh.io import output_notebook, output_file

output_file('line.html')
output_notebook()

x, y = [1,2,3,4,5], [2,4,6,8,10]
fig = figure(title = 'Ejemplo de Linea', x_axis_label = 'x', y_axis_label = 'y')
fig.line(x, y)
show(fig)
```

El resultado sería el siguiente

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

### **Sobre Node.js y npm**

En el reporte también se lee lo siguiente:

```
node.js version     :  (not installed)
npm version         :  (not installed)
```

Es decir que tu ordenador no posee [node.js](https://nodejs.org/es/) ni npm. A no ser que estés trabajando Python y el jupyter notebook en algún ambiente virtual y eso esté generando alguna especie de conflicto... aunque no creo, porque node.js y npm se instala por lo general de forma global.

Te aconsejo que de acuerdo a tu sistema operativo veas algún tutorial sobre como se instalan y configuran dichas tecnologías... aquí puedes descargar ambas https://www.npmjs.com/get-npm

Comment: Efectivamente, estoy trabajando en un entorno virtual. Voy a ver cómo instalar y configurar esas tecnologías. No obstante, hay un detalle que quizás te pasó desapercibido. ¿Por qué si abro un notebook nuevo, en la misma sesión, ese script muestra la figura correctamente en el  nuevo notebook?. Gracias por tu ayuda.

Comment: Hubert. He hecho la siguiente prueba. En el notebook que reproduce el fallo, he ejecutado Restart & Clera Out.  He seleccionado todas las celdas y, seguidamente, ls he copiado en un nuevo notebook. En este nuevo libro, el fallo ya no se reproduce. ¿Te da alguna pista más de cuál puede ser la causa de la contaminación el primer notebook?.  De este modo. he conseguido salvar cinco horas de trabajo. He instalado node.js mediante conda. Lo que veo más complicado es instalar npm ..ya veré.

Comment: Realmente no sé si esta sea la causa que vos me comenta... cuando estás en un entorno virtual y agregas el kernel u otro biblioteca, si el entorno virtual no está activado (`source mi_entorno/bin/activate`).., estás no se encontrará disponible... en este [enlace inglés](https://janakiev.com/blog/jupyter-virtual-envs/) hay más detalle. Otro podría ser, que se haya desconfigurado (mac, ubuntu) el [~/.bashrc](https://www.enmimaquinafunciona.com/pregunta/44151/que-es-un-bashrc-archivo-y-que-hace) es decir, se ha agregado al path rutas, que estén apuntando a otra versión de python por ejemplo.

Comment: Aunque esta no parece ser la causa del fallo objeto de esta consulta, gracias a tu sugerencia he descubierto que no tenía muy bien configurado el entorno virtual, dado que desconocía la conveniencia de hacer el segundo paso "Add Virtual Environment to Jupyter Notebook", lo cual viene muy bien explicado en tu enlace. Muchas gracias.